# actionlib_java installation

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have made a ros base application that uses actionlib_java. The hg contains
./,
../,
actionlib_java/,
apache_commons_util/,
apache_xmlrpc/,
CMakeLists.txt,
.hg/,
.hgignore,
.hgtags,
Makefile,
misc/,
pom.xml,
README,
rosdep.yaml,
rosjava/,
rosjava_bootstrap/,
rosjava-dev.rosinstall,
rosjava.rosinstall,
rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/,
stack.xml,
and test_rosjava/

This works well and runs everything.
Now I want to transfer my application to another computer. I can not compile the rosjava based nodes. Of course I need actionlib_java and rosjava things. I found hg on https://code.google.com/r/damonkohler-rosjava-unstable/ I install it but it does not work becasue it have rosjav_actionlib not actionlib_java. Does anyone know where hg containing stabel actionlib_java exists...Or any other solution to make my application run. It seems that I had old rosjava and actionlib_java versions 0.0.0 and they are now unstable or not avaiable????
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35342/actionlib_java--installation/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/37198/rosjava-actionlib/

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0